Elimination of imaginaries in divisible ordered abelian groups
For a complete theory $T$ and saturated $M\models T$, elimination of imaginaries can be defined as the following: for every definable set $D$ (possibly defined with parameters) in $M^n$ admits a code, which means that there is $e\in M^m$ such that $\sigma(e)=e$ iff $\sigma(D)=D$ for $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(M)$.
For the theory of divisble abelian groups (DOAG), I know that it eliminates imaginaries (can be proved by Hrushovski's criterion: density of definable types + code definable types + code finite sets) and it does not uniformly eliminate quantifiers (by $|\text{dcl}(\varnothing)|=1$ obtained from quantifier elimination).
Now I want a proof of elimination of imaginaries without using Hrushovski's criterion (I'm not sure whether the proof of using it is even true, because in the criterion, we have to assume that the theory has a dominant valued field sort). Since DOAG is o-minimal, for definable sets in $M^1$ it is clear, but in $M^n$ (n>1), I'm not sure how to do it.
